# Higher amount of options from adding counting principle than fundamental counting principle

Tags: combinatorics

The question was posed as: 
I have a number of dogs and monkeys living with me. If I decide to take out for a walk a monkey AND a dog, I find I have fewer options than if I decide to take out a monkey OR a dog.

What can you say about the numbers of monkeys and dogs I live with?

Fully explain your answer.

What I have so far:

md< m+d

therefore m(d-m)< d

if you were to have one monkey and two dogs, and you inputted the values, they would prove themselves correct

1(2)<1+2

2<3

1(2-1)<2

1(1)<2

1<2

If you chose to walk a monkey and a dog, you would have 2 options. The difference being which dog.

If you chose to walk you have three, either a monkey or one of the two dogs.

I am unsure because of the part of the question that asks: What can you say about the numbers of monkeys and dogs I live with?

It would seem as though the numbers would be more extravagant than just 1 and 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the question meant that the OR was interpreted as XOR, then how about interpreting as follows...

m*d < m+d

1 < 1/m + 1/d

I assume the question asserts that m and d are both greater than 0. Yet, if one were 0, then as long as the other were non zero then the inequality holds.

Let's assume that one of m or d is 1.

m = 1, then d can be any number greater than or equal to 1.

m = 2, then d must be 1.  Two fails because half plus half is equal to one but not greater.

You can then conclude that you have one dog (monkey) and an arbitrary but fixed amount of monkeys (dogs).

If the OR is to be interpreted not as an XOR, then the results seem intuitive.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help and clarification!